# Custom option file path "[fullpath] => /var/www" in magento 1.8 not able to open it on download

Tags: magento-1.8, custom-options, file-permissions

I have Magento 1.8 setup, if I try to print info array in this file

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/DownloadContorlleres.php
```

it is printing the full path as below

> /var/www/html/media/custom_options/quot/w/i/f8e5fcf046a0b213588f15b3d63312d3.jpg

I am not able to download or open the same path.
On accessing it with the base url /media/custom_options/quote/w/i/f8e5fcf046a0b213588f15b3d63312d3.jpg it throws the error ->
You don't have permission to access /media/custom_options/quote/w/i/f8e5fcf046a0b213588f15b3d63312d3.jpg on this server.

Comment: Also when passing the file path with base url as stated above still on download i am not table to open the file

Answer (score 0):

You cannot download or open as it is the physical path of the file. The physical path cannot be opened through the browser. If path looks like

`www.website.com/media/custom_options/quote/w/i/f8e5fcf046a0b213588f15b3d63312d3.jpg`

then you can download the file.

I think you are getting the directory path instead of base URL. Check this, it will work.

Comment: Thanks Kalyan..But when i tried to edit it with the base url as you told then i still have the same issue :(    The error is "You don't have permission to access /media/custom_options/quote/w/i/f8e5fcf046a0b213588f15b3d63312d3.jpg on this server."

Comment: please show what is the complete URL of the image. Also, try to give 777 permission to the media folder, maybe that is the issue.

Comment: https://mywebsite.com/media/custom_options/quote/w/i/f8e5fcf046a0b213588f15b3d63312d3.jpg

Comment: Also i have give 777 to media and its sub directories